# Adding SSH keys to Git

Tags: github, macos-sierra, ssh-keys

I'm unable to add a new SSH key to GitHub, the SSH key pair that I've generated is `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. When I've tried to add these to my account in GitHub I'm told that the key is invalid, so I've tried various combinations, like `ssh-id_rsa`, based on the suggestions given in the error message.

In GitHub help it says:

```
'If you're using macOS Sierra 10.12.2 or later, you will need to modify 
your ~/.ssh/config file to automatically load keys into the ssh-agent 
and store passphrases in your keychain.'
```

I'm using Sierra 10.12.2, but I haven't found any way of modifying or creating a ssh/config file, so I think this might be preventing me from adding my public key to my GitHub account.

Any tips would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: How did you generate the ssh key?  Brew?

Comment: In the terminal with $ssh-keygen, so I was also given a key fingerprint and a randomart image

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are talking about - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots

You need to update your bash_profile.